# myheadings in memoir - chapter title verso and recto page

Tags: header-footer, memoir, chapters

I wrote a book with memoir. My last problem is, that I have a chapter, which is so short, that it has no sections. This leads to the fact that on the recto page there is an empty header. How can I make memoir write the chaptertitle also in the header of the recto page.

```
\RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openright,showtrims]{memoir}
\stockaiv
\raggedbottom
%%% set up the page layout
\settrims{42.5mm}{31mm}
\settrimmedsize{21cm}{14.8cm}{*}
\settypeblocksize{18cm}{11,5cm}{*}  

\flushbottom
%Rand rechts und links auf dem geschnittenen Papier
\setlrmargins{15mm}{*}{*}
%Rand oben und unten auf dem zugeschnittenen Papier 
\setulmarginsandblock{15mm}{10mm}{*}

\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{\onelineskip}
\setheaderspaces{*}{5mm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
%ZEICHEN
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    

%SPRACHEN
\usepackage[english,polish,french,ngerman]{babel}

\def\mychapterstyle{komalike}
\def\mypagestyle{headings}
\nouppercaseheads
\def\revision{}
```

I know it is not the nicest piece of preamble. It grew dynamically in time.
Thank you for any advice and help!!

Comment: What about `\chapter{Short chapter}\thispagestyle{myheadings}`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! With `memoir` you should use its own interface for modifying headings, so either the commands given in the manual for changing things or use `\renewcommand` to modify those commands. I wouldn't recommend `\def\mypagestyle` when the class already has a mechanism for setting pagestyles. Also, load packages after documentclass.

Comment: Hi Werner thanks for your answer. Sorry to say, that it does not work that way. The \thispagestyle{empty} command I used to get rid of the pagenumber on the first page of the chapter. I need a way to put the chaptertitle in the header of the third page of that short chapter.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your comment. Well, to be onest, I was not succesfull in using the def\mypagestyle commands, and I spent already quite some time with the memmman. That is why I try to get some help here.

Comment: I'm not at a computer at the moment. But this is easy to fix, it should be something like `\addtopsmarks{myheadings} {} {\createmark{chapter}{both} {prechapnum}{postchapnum} } \pagestyle{myheadings} `. I do not remember the pre and postchapnum for myheadings

Comment: @Chris: So your chapter is short and has how many pages? Page 1 is the first chapter page. Then there is a page two. What is on page 3? What is on page 4?

Answer (score 1):

Your MWE does not even use `myheadings`, but here is a MWE with `headings`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\addtopsmarks{headings}{}{
  % changed left to both
  \createmark{chapter}{both}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{. \ }
}
\makeatother
\nouppercaseheads
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}

\chapter{test}

\lipsum[1-15]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thank you so much, daleif!!! Now my manuskript meets the expectations of the publisher. So happy!